# How to edit Commerce to display more than 3 products in a row

Tags: views, commerce

I'm using **Commerce Kickstart**, I am not able to figure out how to display more than 3 **products** in a row. Even if I created a new View mode using **Entity View Mode** it still behaves the same.

How shall I go about changing this? Is there a setting somewhere in the View UI that's controlling this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Think I found a way to resolve this simply via CSS.

There is this styles in global.css:

> .page-products .view-display-products li:nth-child(3n+4) { 
>       clear: left;
>       /* LTR */
>       float: left;
>       /** LTR */ 
> }

so we can overwrite it with a sub-theme CSS with "**clear:none**".

By re-sizing browser window, looks like it still works well when window get smaller.

Earlier on didn't quite look close enough into this, partly due to meddling too  much in Views Format settings. So assuming reverting to default Views setting, the above CSS change should work fine. Will update again if otherwise.

BK :)